# Amazon MWS API: generating FNSKU before listing to inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

Based on my research in the MWS API documentation, it seems that the only way to list products to inventory is using the submit feed operation, and posting a flat inventory loader file, which takes minutes to process and has an unforgiving API rate limit.

However, I noticed that when I list using Inventory Lab, they are able to generate the FNSKU for items that have not been uploaded to inventory.

If I try to create an FNSKU through creating an inbound shipment plan, Amazon gives me an error saying that the seller SKU is invalid (which makes sense, because it has no record of that SKU).

Is there a trick here?

Comment: There are many different ways to create skus besides MWS. Also the api rate limit is for separate feeds not the products themselves. you can have hundreds of products in one feed.

Comment: How else could you generate an FNSKU? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Specifically, the problem is that I can't do a batch upload. I have to be able to generate the FNSKU right after they scan and select a specific ASIN, and I hit the rate limit if I try to use submit feed hundreds of times in a few minutes.

Comment: not sure - but inventory lab has to be creating the product first. creating a product and setting its inventory are separate feeds. not sure if this will help you but i did find this tutorial http://www.blastar.biz/2014/10/18/tutorial-fetching-stock-data-from-amazon-using-fbainventoryservicemws/